# Commands to grep search username on an IRC channel

Tags: irc

Looks like i need to use `/names #channel` but it doesn't seem to work on Slack IRC. *I setup ZNC as an IRC bouncer for my Slack team chat.*

Is there any other command that can achieve the same thing?

Comment: care to elaborate? your question isn't very clear.

Comment: @TD.512 we use Slack as our internal chat/collaboration tool. Slack supports IRC gateway. I would like to search for a person. i know their name but i dont know their Slack(IRC) username.